# Wordpress WP_Query search both title and content?

Tags: php, wordpress

The "s" parameter in WP_Query() only search the title?
How do I make it search content only?
How do I make it search both title & content?

Comment: I was planning to use post_search filter, but I don't see any documentation at http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_search.

Answer (score 1):

Ahhhh, I found a solution.

```
         function where_title_only($where_clause) {
                return ($where_clause." AND `post_title` LIKE '%".trim($_POST['k'])."%' ");
         }
         function where_desc_only($where_clause) {
                return ($where_clause." AND `post_content` LIKE '%".trim($_POST['k'])."%' ");
         }
         function where_both($where_clause) {
                return ($where_clause." AND (`post_title` LIKE '%".trim($_POST['k'])."%' "." OR `post_content` LIKE '%".trim($_POST['k'])."%' ) ");
         }

         if (trim($_POST['search_type']) == "title") {
                  add_filter("posts_where","where_title_only");
         }if (trim($_POST['search_type']) == "desc") {
                  add_filter("posts_where","where_desc_only");
         }else{
                  add_filter("posts_where","where_both");
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot filter Query by post content.  You would have to write a function that loops through all posts looking for the field.

Comment: I read an article long time ago, and this is possible using filters! I just can't find back the info.

Comment: Filters are a means to introduce a custom function, which I mention above, so your downvote is invalid. Your question was how to do this with WP_Query, not how to do it with filters.  You wouldn't HAVE to use filters unless you wanted to modify how WP_Query functions, which again was not your question, specifically.

Comment: I suppose it was deserved since it probably should have been a comment.  Glad you found it though.  Bookmarked. :D